background-position and background-size doesn't fit element
I'm trying to divide it into 4 parts horizontally using size and position, but it doesn't fit.
Is it possible to achieve this using this method?


.ui-button {
    display: block;
    padding: 12px 10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 1;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
.ui-button {
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 2em;
    background: #e97820;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.ui-button{
      background:
        linear-gradient(180deg, #880021 50%, #B97A57 50%),
        linear-gradient(0deg, #880021 50%, #B97A57 50%),
        linear-gradient(180deg, #880021 50%, #B97A57 50%),
        linear-gradient(0deg, #880021 50%, #B97A57 50%);
    background-position: 0% 0%, 25% 0%, 50% 0%, 100% 100%;
    background-size: 25%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="ui-button" value="start">




you don't need 4 gradients, one gradient can do it background: repeating-conic-gradient(red 0 25%,blue 0 50%) 0/50% 100%

Percentage positions are a little tricky to get your head around. In terms of horizontal position:

0% means that the left edge of the background will be aligned with the left edge of the element
100% means that the right edge of the background will be aligned with the right edge of the element
50% means that the center of the background will be aligned with the center of the element

The simplest way to figure out the correct values can be through trial-and-error. Experimenting with your question, I quickly discovered that relevant horizontal positions you need for the four background gradients are 0%, 33.33%, 66.67% and 100%.
So your position declaration needs to be as follows:
background-position: 0% 0%, 33.33% 0%, 66.67% 0%, 100% 0%;



body {
  background: silver;
}

.ui-button {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5em 2em;
  font-size: 22px;
  border: 3px solid white;
  border-radius: 2em;
  background: #e97820;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
  background:
    linear-gradient(180deg, #880021 50%, #B97A57 50%),
    linear-gradient(0deg, #880021 50%, #B97A57 50%),
    linear-gradient(180deg, #880021 50%, #B97A57 50%),
    linear-gradient(0deg, #880021 50%, #B97A57 50%);
  background-position: 0% 0%, 33.33% 0%, 66.67% 0%, 100% 0%;
  background-size: 25%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="ui-button" value="start">



Or you could use the suggestion from @TemaniAfif:


body {
  background: silver;
}

.ui-button {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5em 2em;
  font-size: 22px;
  border: 3px solid white;
  border-radius: 2em;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
  background: repeating-conic-gradient(#B97A57 0 25%, #880021 0 50%) 0/50% 100%;  
}
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="ui-button" value="start">



